# How do I structure OOP and OOD in a larger PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, oop, design-patterns, structure

I'm not sure how to structure a larger PowerShell script that uses classes, and I cannot find anything.  I have five classes in one file.  How do I call them without a main class?  Is it proper to create a standalone script that simply instantiates the other classes and calls them?

In PowerShell, most everything I see is based on functions, not classes.  And, PowerShell OOP and OOD it isn't *exactly* like designing OOP in the C# or Java sense.  There is a lot the same concepts, but the structure is eluding me.  It isn't enough to have keywords and classes, if I cannot design with them in a comprehensive way.

What search am I missing, they keywords?  How should I structure my script?  I have a lot of PowerShell classes already that I'd like to put into Production.  Now what?

I've searched, and I've looked on SO and Github, but do not know what's "right."

My particular case is using v5, but other times I have access to v7, if that matters.  I have, for example:

```
class A
{

}

class B
{

}

class C
{

}
```

There's no `Main` to start things off in PowerShell.

Answer (score 6):

> There's no `Main` to start things off in PowerShell.

The *top-level scope* of your script (`.ps1` file) is the equivalent of a `Main`  entry point. That is, any statements outside class class and function definitions are executed.

You're free to place `class` definitions anywhere in your script, as they are parsed *before* execution (this contrasts with *functions*, whose definitions must be placed *before* code that calls them).

Alternatively, you can place `class`es:

- in a *separate `.ps1` file* that you must then [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) in your main script, *before* attempting to use them.

  - E.g., to dot-source `classes.ps1` located in the same folder as your script:

    ```sh
    . $PSScriptRoot/classes.ps1
    ```
- in a supporting [*module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), which your main script must import via a [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/About_Using) statement at the start of your script ([`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) does *not* work, because it doesn't import classes)

  - E.g., in the simplest case, if your classes are located in a stand-alone `classes.psm1` script-module file in the same folder as the script:

    ```sh
    # Place at the top; no other statements (except other `using` ones) 
    # allowed before it.
    using module ./classes.psm1
    ```

Note:

- Unless you need your classes to be used from *multiple* scripts, potentially via [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading), there is no benefit to using a module.
- A **general caveat**:

  - `class`es are a relatively late addition to the PowerShell language and, in terms of features, are *not* on par with C#'s classes - neither currently (see [GitHub issue #6652](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652) for list of current problems), nor is that the design goal.
  - While PowerShell is perfectly capable of *operating on* objects (class instances), most typically by accessing their *properties*, less often by calling their *methods*, the PowerShell language itself is *not* object-centric and uses an imperative control flow based on commands (scripts, functions, external programs).
  - For that reason - rather than trying to structure PowerShell code as if it were a C# application - **it is advisable to limit the use of `class`es to providing occasional helper classes, such as strongly-typed "property bags"**, while implementing the control flow via scripts, functions, and cmdlets.